# Creating a quiz page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was trying to create a simple quiz page using Javascript. Else it went well, but after I run this code in browser, on pressing submit button the DOM text appeared in paragraph(through Script) disappears just after  a flash. I had expected the text to remain on screen until the next action. Please help me troubleshoot this problem.

Thank you

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Quiz
</title>
  <script type = "text/Javascript">

 function checkAnswers()

         {

            var myQuiz = document.getElementById( "myQuiz" );

            if ( myQuiz.elements[ 2 ].checked )
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Congrats, Thats the Right answer";

                else 

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Woops!! The Correct answer is 'Mouse'.<br>Click 'Next' to Proceed";

         } 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<form id = "myQuiz" onsubmit = "checkAnswers()" action = "">

Which among the following is readily found in computers ?
<br><br><br>
<input type = "radio" name = "radiobutton" value = "A" /><label> Zebra</label>

<input type = "radio" name = "radiobutton" value = "B" /><label> Girrafe</label>
<br><br> <input type = "radio" name = "radiobutton" value = "C" /><label>Mouse</label>

<input type = "radio" name = "radiobutton" value = "D" /><label>Mosquito</label>

</div><br><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" />
<br>

<p id = "demo" "> </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't want to send the results to the server, just use a button instead of submit. If you want to submit, your server code has to also write the text on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes:

HTML

```
<form id = "myQuiz" onsubmit = "checkAnswers(event)" action = "">
```

JS

```
function checkAnswers(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}
```

[`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) cancels the form submit event which is causing the page to reload and your text to disappear.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fyoequrn/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just return "false" inside the onSubmit parameter, like this:

```
<form id = "myQuiz" onsubmit = "return false" action = "">
```

And invoke the `checkAnswers()` function when someone clicks the button;

```
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick="checkAnswers()" />
```